# Is a locally $\mathcal{C}$ space a direct limit of $\mathcal{C}$ spaces?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a class of topological spaces (for example Hausdorff spaces, compact spaces, connected spaces, finite spaces, etc...), and let $X$ be a topological space. Is the following true?

> (L): $X$ is locally $\mathcal{C}$ if and only if $X$ is a direct limit of spaces belonging to $\mathcal{C}$.

This question came to my mind when I realized that $\Bbb{R}$, as a topological space, is the direct limit of the system $\{ [-n,n] : n >0 \}$ where the maps are inclusions. All the spaces $[-n,n]$ are compact, and indeed $\Bbb{R}$ is locally compact.

After that, I investigated a bit on the nature of being "locally compact". Suppose $X$ is locally compact. Then for every point $x \in X$ there exists a compact neighbourhood $A_x$ of $x$. Set $$\mathcal{A} = \{ A \subset X : A  \mbox{ is compact and $A$ has nonempty interior} \}$$ and partial order this family by inclusion. This is a direct system of compact spaces since the union of two compact spaces is compact $(*)$.
Then we can see that $X = \lim_{\to} \mathcal{A}$ simply checking that the universal property is satisfied.

So (if I made no mistakes), I concluded that every locally compact space is a direct limit of compact spaces.

Now, if I want to replace in the above argument "compact" with "is in the class $\mathcal{C}$", I realize that condition $(*)$ is not necessarily satisfied. And here I got stuck.

Please, I would be very happy if I knew that (L) is true, at least for some particular cases (e.g. for locally compact spaces), but before I proceed my investigation I want to know if it is worth to continue.

Comment: By "direct limit" you probably mean "filtered colimit in $\mathsf{Top}$"?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes.

Comment: You don't require that the transition maps are embeddings?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg No, I don't.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that locally compact spaces are filtered colimits of compact spaces, but the converse is not true:

If $X$ is a normed vector space, then its unit ball $B$ is locally compact if and only if $B$ is compact if and only if $X$ is finite-dimensional. Applying this to $X=\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, wee see that the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is not locally compact. But it is the colimit of the unit balls of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n \geq 0$, which are compact.

*Warning.* There is probably a mistake here, because the norm-topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ does not seem to coincide with the colimit-topology.

Comment: I understand what $\Bbb{R}^{\infty}$ is, and that its unit ball is not locally compact. Actually I don't see why it is the colimit of finite dimensional unit balls. Clearly, it is the union (as sets), but is it actually the colimit in $\mbox{Top}$?

Comment: You are right, this is not clear at all! If $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is a subset whose intersection with each $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it is not clear to me why $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ (w.r.t. the norm-topology), because for a given point of $U$ the radii which witness openness in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ may converge to zero. On the other hand, it is claimed everywhere that $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is the colimit of the $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Or do they only mean the underlying sets? Or do they use the colimit-topology as a definition?)